# Use Javascript variable in Symfony path (Ajax request)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony, symfony4

I've created a Ajax request who posts data to a Symfony path. Inside my Symfony path I want to use a Javascript variable to generate my route.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            function cbOnClick(cb) {
                cbValue = cb.checked;
                todoId = cb.getAttribute('data-id');

                $.ajax({
                    url: '{{ (path('change_todo_status', {'todo_id': todoId})) }}',
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        "status": "cbValue"
                    },
                    async: true,
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data)
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Inside my url I want to set the todoId, but I'm getting te error the variable "todoId" does not exists.

Comment: You are using an external JS file, aren't you?

Comment: No, it's not is an external file. This script is at the bottom of my twig file

Comment: It has nothing to do with the parameters from the controller. The parameters (todoId) is a Javascript variable based on a onClick event -> `todoId = cb.getAttribute('data-id');`

Comment: Ah I didn't noticed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `'{{ (path('change_todo_status', {'todo_id': todoId})) }}'`, twig expects a twig variable. I already had that issue and I used a placeholder to be replaced in javascript.

In example :

```
let todoId = cb.getAttribute('data-id');
/*
 * this will generate a path with ReplaceMeWithCorrectValue instead of the correct value.
 * You have to use a placeholder that correspond to the restrictions defined in your route.
 */
let url = "{{ (path('change_todo_status', {'todo_id': 'ReplaceMeWithCorrectValue'})) }}";

url = url.replace("ReplaceMeWithCorrectValue", todoId);
```

And then, in your ajax :

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
   // the remain of your code
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Fixed it